# ExecuteNonQuery() for Insert query always returning 0

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, executenonquery

I have the following code in a VB.net application that runs a stored procedure in MS Access.  The stored procedure is an insert query based on the results of 2 other queries in the database.

When I run the Insert query manually within Access it runs fine and inserts the records as expected with no error or warnings.  However, when I run using the ExecuteNonQuery() from my vb.net application I always get 0 back as the number of records inserted and it doesn't insert any records into the table.  The code runs without errors.  I have tested the code with other insert queries in the same db and it works fine so I know it's not the code or connection.  It appears the problem has something to do with my query, but I can't figure out why it works in Access, but not from ExecuteNonQuery().  Sorry, but I can't post the exact query.  I'm using VB.Net 2010 and MS Access 2013.

Please help!!!

Here is a generic version of my stored query:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( TESTID, Field1, Field2, Field3, DateImported )
SELECT DISTINCT Table2.Value1, Table2.Value2, Table2.Value3, Table2.Value4, Date() AS TodaysDate
FROM Table3 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table3.TESTID = Table2.TESTID
```

I have tried it with and without the DISTINCT and I still have the same problem

Here is my code:

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(MyConnectionString)

Try

    Using conn

      Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("My_Insert_Query", conn)

            conn.Open()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            NumRecordsAdded = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

      End Using

    End Using

Catch ex As Exception

    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    conn.Close()

End Try
```

Comment: You will probably get error on `conn.Close()` because once `end using` executed your `conn` will be disposed. When problem is this weird, your `FROM Table3 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table3.TESTID = Table2.TESTID` must return 0 records because you hitting different DB or something like that.

Comment: I don't think it's hitting a different DB.  When the code runs, I can see the locked accdb file appear as the connection is opened and then go away when the connection closes. Also when I try it with a different query it works fine in the correct db.

Comment: Using same code, only instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` use `ExecuteScalar` to execute `SELECT count(1) FROM Table3 INNER JOIN Table2 ON  Table3.TESTID = Table2.TESTID`. And see if `count` is `0`

Comment: Your code does not add any parameters to your `OleDbCommand` object.  How does your stored procedure know what to insert?

Comment: It is inserting records from one table that don't exist in the destination table.   I've also tried another query using a left join between the two tables that checks for null key in destination table.   It also works perfectly when manually run in Acess, but has same problem as original when run from code.